# pjsip2.5 local sdp port erro

Tags: c, pjsip, sdp

config_site.h

```
#define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO 1

pjsua_config_default(&app_config.cfg);
app_config.cfg.cb.on_incoming_call = &on_incoming_call;
app_config.cfg.cb.on_call_media_state = &on_call_media_state;
app_config.cfg.cb.on_call_state = &on_call_state;
app_config.cfg.cb.on_dtmf_digit = &call_on_dtmf_callback;
app_config.cfg.cb.on_reg_state2=&on_reg_state_callback;
app_config.cfg.cb.on_call_sdp_created=&on_call_sdp_created;

pjsua_call_setting  call_opt

pjsua_call_setting  call_opt;
pjsua_call_setting_default(&call_opt);
call_opt.aud_cnt=1;
call_opt.flag=PJSUA_CALL_UNHOLD;
call_opt.req_keyframe_method=PJSUA_VID_REQ_KEYFRAME_SIP_INFO;
call_opt.vid_cnt=1;
```

Add local account

```
pjsua_acc_add_local(transport_id, PJ_TRUE, &aid);

/* Adjust local account config based on pjsua app config */
{
     pjsua_acc_config acc_cfg;
    pjsua_acc_get_config(aid, tmp_pool, &acc_cfg);

    acc_cfg.rtp_cfg = app_config.rtp_cfg;
    app_config_init_video(&acc_cfg);
    acc_cfg.rtp_cfg = app_config.rtp_cfg;
    pjsua_acc_modify(aid, &acc_cfg);
}
```

The phone calls in for the first time, and the second time will quit.

> voip: ../src/pjsip-ua/sip_inv.c:1135: pjsip_inv_verify_request3:
>   Assertion (status=pjmedia_sdp_validate(l_sdp))==PJ_SUCCESS' failed.

Why is `l_sdp` unavailable?

Answer (score 0):

`config_site.h  #define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO 0`

Disable video, it is normal

Is there a problem with the settings?